# Avoiding foreignkey constraint in JPA for an entity?

Tags: java, jpa

I am working with a webservice module of a huge application. the application may have around 200 tables in database. My service database layer is JPA and only need to map 6 tables by 6 entities. Also the service is intended only for read data (no insert/update/delete).

My problem is that one of my 6 tables,say `product_table` has 4 foreign key relationship with someother tables and if I include these too, from my observation I need to include around 16 more entities to keep these relations. But I don't need these.

If we can skip the foreign key relationships for `product_table` form my corresponding `Product` JPA entity, without changing constraints of `product_table` database ?

Is there any such provision in JPA?

Comment: Yeah, just don't map them. Either skip the field completely, or model it as a plain `int` rather than a foreign key/separate entity. You don't *have* to model the DB completely via entities

Comment: Oh. Then even if the table posses constraints we can ignore irrelevant ones in the entity? That is what i am looking for.

Comment: Well if you're not writing it's fine. If you do try to write the DB might act up.